# Graylog2 Quick Setup Wizard has inactive Connect to MongoDB button in Ubuntu/Firefox

Tags: ubuntu, graylog2

Ubuntu 12.04, Firefox 31.0, graylog2-setup-0.91.3.tar.gz, Java 7

I've been working with the Quick Setup instructions but am having trouble connecting to the MongoDB as per http://www.graylog2.org/getting-started/step/1/guide/quick-setup/chapter/3

I've completed the steps before this point, and have the message to open whatever.local:10000 in my browser.  Following that, I have done step "1. Install MongoDB", following the link to docs.mongodb.org and running through those steps and can start, stop, restart, and "$ mongo" gives me the MongoDB shell.
Believing I'm done there, I clicked the Next Step button (mouseover gives a hand cursor) and it opens up the next step:

"2. Connect to MongoDB".  This pod has Host, Port, Database boxes pre-populated with the defaults (127.0.0.1, 27017, graylog2_setup) and a toggle to give a username and password (which I don't need right now).

Problem:   The "CONNECT TO MONGODB AND PROCEED" button doesn't work and doesn't have a mouseover cursor change, so I cannot continue.  If I sneak ahead to 3, the Next Step button is dimmed until I put valid info in the account creation boxes, then it undims, but is likewise inactive.

Is there something really clever here that activates this button only when MongoDB is running correctly thus I haven't really completed the MongoDB install?  Or is my Mozilla Firefox 31.0 not doing something? Or other?

Shall I stop trying the Quick Setup?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using Chrome on OSX. I used Safari instead and it worked.